# Spring JavaMailSenderImpl Sending Mail from localhost

Tags: spring

I'm using tomcat 7 and Spring 3.0.5 and I'm trying to send email using JavaMailSenderImpl. In order to send mail from my own computer (localhost).  I'm able to send email on the real server using the below host/port, but not my local pc. Any ideas?

```
JavaMailSenderImpl sender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
sender.setHost("localhost");
sender.setPort(25);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to send an email your Spring client need to connect to an SMTP server (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol). 
If you don't run an SMTP server on localhost the above code will never work.

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/DevNullSmtp.jsp for a dummy test smtp server or if you plan to unit test your mail sending logic use Wiser https://github.com/voodoodyne/subethasmtp/blob/master/Wiser.md